# Unable to add delimiters & filename with words in Wordcount Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This is the Mapreduce function. What i am doing is concatenating Delimiters "######" & my file's name with WOrd in the WORDCOunt class. When i run the code i get no change . I just get Words & their counts.
I want the final result in this format (Word ###### Filename). Please, tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
   public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable ,  Text ,  Text ,  Text > 
   {
          private final static IntWritable one  = new IntWritable( 1);
          private Text word  = new Text();
          private static final Pattern WORD_BOUNDARY = Pattern .compile("\\s*\\b\\s*");

          public void map( LongWritable offset,  Text lineText,  Context context) throws  IOException,  InterruptedException 
          {
             String line  = lineText.toString();
             Text currentWord  = new Text();

             //These lines will split the files.
             InputSplit input_split = context.getInputSplit();
             String FName = ((FileSplit) input_split).getPath().getName();

             for ( String word  : WORD_BOUNDARY .split(line)) 
             {
                if (word.isEmpty()) 
                {
                   continue;
                }
                //These lines will add delimiters with the words & filename. 
                currentWord  = new Text(word + "####" + FName);
                context.write(new Text(currentWord.toString()), new Text (FName));
             }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Where is your reducer class ? It might have something which may cause this.

Comment: Side comment: Is MapReduce a requirement? No one I've met really writes it in production

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved. The code was already working fine. I had an issue with running the wrong commands on terminal.